# Using semicolons in lists

Tags: grammar, semicolons

I am trying to write a business article where I need to use a signal phrase/cite/mention the credibility of the authors. I'm having trouble with a certain sentence, and was hoping to get some feedback on the correct sentence structure. Right now, it is written as the following:

> According to research conducted by Hannah Payne, research associate; Marin Christensen, research associate; and Dr. Susan Madsen, a professor at Utah State University, Utah ranked last among the 50 states for women's equality in 2021.

I'm not very familiar with using semicolons within lists, and I'm not sure if there is a better way to phrase this sentence... any suggestions? Normally in a paper I would leave out the titles, but I just know my professor would take points off by saying something like, "Who is this?" Or "Fallacious appeal to anonymous authority" or something.

Comment: ...conducted by Hannah Payne (research associate), Marin Christensen (research associate) and ...

Comment: According to research conducted by research associates Hannah Payne and Marin Christensen, and Utah State University Professor Susan Madsen, Utah ranked last among the 50 states for women's equality in 2021. Simpler and better. Cheers. By the way, this is editing which is not really allowed here.

Comment: I like Lambie's suggestion but I would omit the first comma.